# How to connect to server via ssh but use native "Connect to Server" in OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh

I have a remote server I manage via command line on Snow Leopard. I ssh into it, etc. All of my ssh keys are setup, and I have configured a local alias that lets me login with one command. What I'd also like to do is be able to connect to it via ssh, but have it mounted locally as a remote drive.

I've tried the Connect to Server, command-k, but when I try the address as "ssh://myusername@the.IP.address" I get a warning from OS X:

```
URLs should begin with afp://, cifs://, ftp://, ftps://, http://, https://, nfs://, smb:// or vnc://
```

So how, if possible, can I mount my remote server as a drive and have it using the existing secured ssh keys I have already configured?

Comment: Should be on http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want [sshfs](http://google.com/p/macfuse/wiki/MACFUSE_FS_SSHFS) from the MacFUSE project.

Comment: Yup, I've been working at getting it setup but man, is this thing out of date. The documentation is all over the place, with some referencing features that were changed or removed in Leopard and Snow Leopard. *Not* the easiest thing to configured, by any means.